# How can I overwrite all images width in php html?

Tags: php, html, css, image, resize

I would like to overwrite all images width to 90% percent. But there are some pictures have the styles in css file, some looks like this:

```
 <img src="sss" style="something" ...
```

I vanna dell all style things in the mobile version of website.

This is it: http://mikrobusz-berles.com The pictures are too big. I wanna resize them for mobile version. Any idea?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanna change the width to 90% if a user is using a mobile phone you can do something like this.

write a CSS class as follows:

```
.mobile-image {
    width: 90% !important;
}
```

Now use jquery to know if a user is using a mobile phone and then use the `addClass()` method as follows to add the above css class to all the images.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check if a user is logged in using a Mobile Phone or a Handheld Device.
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        // To adjust the width
        $('img').addClass('mobile-image');
        // To Remove style attribute
        $('img').attr('style') = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use an output buffer (read on the manual)
it would capture the whole page with

```
 ob_start();

 //Content here
 $contents=ob_get_flush();
```

And use some regex on $contents to overwrite the width and them echo the $contents

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file:

```
.jFlowSlideContainer img{
   width:99.9%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the styles again using jquery.
Code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){
    $('img').css('width','50%');
});
```

This code is for jquery mobile which you're using.